# Is it possible to get all items using get_internal?

Tags: eve

I have a need to be able to retrieve all items for a particular resource via a custom route. when I use the function as such `get_internal("users", **{"role": item["_id"]})` I am only able to retrieve 50 users. Is there a way to tell get_internal to get all matching items? even if the number of items exceeds the `PAGINATION_DEFAULT` setting? Also is there any documentation on the `<method>_internal` functions?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [PAGINATION_LIMIT](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/config.html?highlight=PAGINATION_LIMIT), [PAGINATION_DEFAULT](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/config.html?highlight=PAGINATION_DEFAULT) and [QUERY_MAX_RESULTS](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/config.html?highlight=QUERY_MAX_RESULTS). (Sorry, links only highlight the words in the page)