# How to disable pagination for a single request (request all items under resource)?

Tags: python-3.x, eve

I have an Eve instance running and pagination enabled. In some cases I want to request all items under a resource. This is done together with a projection to get a full list of ids.

This question is very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312253/is-it-possible-to-get-all-items-using-get-internal), but this question concerns external requests rather than internal calls.

I have tried setting `max_results` to 0 and -1 but both yield a single result. Is there a way to request all items without disabling pagination globally?

**Edit** My current solution to circumvent this is a custom flask endpoint which just access the database directly. The issue with this approach is that I would like to add various projects and make use of Eve's database optimizations. All of which I need to manually reimplement.